# Matlab subscript error

Tags: image, matlab, histogram, indices

I am writing a simple code in matlab which has the purpose of creating the histogram of a grayscale image without using the function hist. I am stuck at the point in which mathlab displays the error "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals." Can you help me finding where is the wrong indices?

```
indirizzo='file.jpg';
immagine=imread(indirizzo);
immaginebn=rgb2gray(immagine);
n=zerps(0,255);
    for x=0:255;
        numeroennesimo=sum(sum(immaginebn==x));
        n(x)=numeroennesimo;
    end
plot(x,n)
```

Comment: "Real or positive integers" seems pretty clear. 0 is not positive, hence not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

you cant use 0 as index. Either make `n(x+1)` or `for x = 1:256` and substract the 1 in your comparison. And there is a typo, I guess it means zeros instead of zerps, which also doesnt work with a 0. And one more, your plot will also not work as the x has only a size of 1 while n is an array of 266 and for a histogram I would use a barplot instead.

```
indirizzo='file.jpg';
immagine=imread(indirizzo);
immaginebn=rgb2gray(immagine);
n=zeros(1,256);
    for x=0:255;
        numeroennesimo=sum(sum(immaginebn==x-1));
        n(x+1)=numeroennesimo;
    end
bar(0:255,n)
```

or

```
indirizzo='file.jpg';
immagine=imread(indirizzo);
immaginebn=rgb2gray(immagine);
n=zeros(1,256);
xplot=zeros(1,256);
    for x=1:256;
        numeroennesimo=sum(sum(immaginebn==x-1));
        n(x)=numeroennesimo;
        xplot(x) = x-1;
    end
plot(xplot,n)
```